# Vertically align graphic on a page by itself

Tags: floats

I have tried several solutions to sort this, such as: `\begin{figure}[p]` and `\vcenter` but nothing works. I would like my graphic to appear in the middle of the page rather than the top. My code is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{rsc}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{mhchem}
\usepackage{adjustbox,lipsum}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{float}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{}
\fancyhead[RE,LO]{\leftmark}
\fancyfoot[CE,CO]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{picture}
    \caption{caption}
    \label{label}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Thank you so much for any help!

EDIT: I know similar questions have been asked before, but the solutions did not work on my file.

Comment: Hi, welcome! Your code *does* place the float vertically centered on the page, and to ensure it even with some text added, you can do as you already tried: `\begin{figure}[p]`. As mentioned in the link Sigur posted, the default behaviour of `p` floats is to be placed in the middle of the page.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, on my file it still is aligned top, even with [p]. Is there anything else in my code which could be affecting it?